# Wrong PDF crop when using the microtype package or zero margin

Tags: pdf, microtype

***[UPDATED]PLEASE READ AT THE BOTTOM OF THE POST[UPDATED]***

I'm still using TexLive 2010 (ubuntu) and I need to create some tight pdf (using `pdflatex` and `pdfcrop` with `--hires` option).

I need to use `microtype`, and also I need to work without margins (I want to create some text strips). The problem is that result pdf are wrong, cutting out some piece of text as you cas see from screenshots.

Removing `microtype`, is working fine in some cases. In others i also need to add some mm to lmargin

This is my `geometry` setup:

```
\usepackage[paperwidth=100mm, paperheight=8.5372222276mm, %
marginparsep=0mm, marginparwidth=0mm, columnsep=0mm,tmargin=0mm,bmargin=0mm,lmargin=0mm,rmargin=0mm,headheight=0mm,headsep=0mm,footskip=0mm]{geometry}
```

Full code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[paperwidth=100mm, paperheight=8.5372222276mm, %
marginparsep=0mm, marginparwidth=0mm, columnsep=0mm,tmargin=0mm,bmargin=0mm,lmargin=0mm,rmargin=0mm,headheight=0mm,headsep=0mm,footskip=0mm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}\setlength{\lineskiplimit}{0pt}\setlength{\lineskip}{0pt}
\begin{document}\frenchspacing
\fontfamily{psb}
\fontsize{20bp}{22}
\selectfont
\textit{``xp}
\end{document}
```

[UPDATED]PLEASE READ AT THE BOTTOM OF THE POST[UPDATED]

### Using mirotype:

[image: With microtype]

### Without microtype:

[image: Without microtype]

How can I fix it?

[UPDATE]

i made some tests.
Please tell me if this solution is correct even in theory:
i need for example a 100mm (width) x 10mm (height), so i add (using common word processor margins as model) 0,49cm (4.9mm) as margin in every margin.

```
\usepackage[paperwidth=109.8mm, paperheight=19.8mm, textwidth=100mm,textheight=10mm]{geometry}
```

Then i compile it with pdflatex and cropped using --hires (pdfcrop). Is it a good and clean solution ? Thank's

Comment: Would you be able to provide the entire document code (in the form of a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)) that was used to produce the images above?

Comment: You should disable character protrusion. Please, add a complete TeX source sample and be more precise about the steps you follow for producing the final PDF.

Comment: Sure, you're right. I added it to main post
Thank you

Comment: Why do you need microtype?

Comment: I use microtype to optimize interword space and because in every latex guide/book i have read. it is suggested to use this package to increase justification quality

Comment: Also disabling microtype (or just protrusion) i have the same issue, it seems that the problem is lmargin=0mm. 

Is there any possibility to set it to 0 and fix the pdf ?

Thank you!

Comment: But obviously you don't want in your case the optimization of microtype. Protrusion e.g. doesn't make sense if you want to generate pdfs with exact bounding boxes. Apart from this: It is always possible that parts of glyphs and other objects stick *outside* their own bounding box. You will have to enlarge the margins or use \strut if you want to make sure nothing is clipped.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I get by compiling

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}\frenchspacing
\fontfamily{ptm}
\fontsize{20bp}{22}
\selectfont
\textit{``xp}
\end{document}
```

and processing the result through `pdfcrop --hires` (I later added a frame, just to show the the result against a white background). I used Times as I don't have Sabon, but that's not the point. Ulrike is mentioning in her comment that characters may have parts outside their bounding box and that's the case, for example, with quotes.

[image]

Here's what's get by compiling Flavio's example and doing `pdfcrop --hires`

[image]

It should be clear what's the correct procedure.

Comment: ok, but how i have to setup geometry package to get a (for example) 100mm text area without the risk of cutted chars ?

Comment: i made some tests. Please tell me if this solution is correct even in theory:

i need for example a 100mm (width) x 10mm (height), so i add (using common word processor margin as model) 0,49cm (4.9mm) as margin in every margin.


{\usepackage[paperwidth=109.8mm, paperheight=19.8mm, %
marginparsep=0mm, marginparwidth=0mm, columnsep=0mm,tmargin=4.9mm,bmargin=4.9mm,lmargin=4.9mm,rmargin=4.9mm,headheight=0mm,headsep=0mm,footskip=0mm]{geometry}
}
Then i compile it with pdflatex and cropped using --margins 1 --hires (pdfcrop).

Is it a good and clean solution ? 

Thank's

Comment: y but time has expired before i edit previous post to format it correctly

Comment: @Flavio It's better to edit your question, than to add long comments.

Comment: question edited, really thank you. Is my new example/idea clear ?